# What command should I use to display specific information about a directory, not its content?

Tags: unix, ls

I need to know how to display info about a directory itself.

I have tried using `ls -l` on the directory where the directory I wanted to know about was in, but had no luck.

Comment: What info do you want of it? `ls -ld directory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command (The -d flag will make ls display only directories):

```
ls -ld directoryname
```

If you are looking for more detailed info, you can use the `stat` command ([more info on stat](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/stat.htm)):

```
stat directoryname
```

Here is an example of what `stat` will return:

[image]

Comment: Oh god, I tried both ls -l and ls -d... I don't know why I didn't thought of mixing them together. Thanks a lot!